# Troubleshooting Java code that refuses to cooperate

Tags: java, string

The string called "code" doesn't seem to read. Why is that and how do I fix it?

My code (the snippet that causes problems):

```
String code;
for(int z = 0; z<x;z= z+0) // Repeat once for every character in the input string remaining
{
    for(int y=0;y<2;y++) //Repeat twice
    {
        c = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a'); //Generate a random character (lowercase)
        ca = Character.toString(c);
        temp = code;
        code = temp + ca; //Add a random character to the encoded string
    }
```

My error report:

```
--------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
H:\Java\Compiler.java:66: variable code might not have been initialized
        temp = code;
               ^
1 error

Process completed.
```

(I am using [JCreator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JCreator) 5.00, Java 7.)

(Yes, the error report looks stupid, but it Stack Overflow reads it as coding.)

Comment: At a first glance, your first loop will not work. You are adding `0` to `z`.

Comment: And the error looks pretty self explanatory unless there is something your not showing us about 'code'

Comment: yes, I know that z+0 does nothing

However, later in the loop, I lower x

Comment: The first loop also has nothing to do with any input string.

Comment: @azulflame Do you lower x for each character in input string? Because that can be accomplished by setting the condition for z to be less than string.length. `for(int z; z < input.length; z++)`

Comment: yes, but x is equal to the remaining characters in the input string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What value would `code` have if `x` is zero?  The answer is it would have no value at all (not even `null`).  You could just initialize it to an empty string if you like:

```
String code = "";
```

Comment: this is a snippet, not the entire program, but I think I see what you're getting at. gimme a sec to test it out.

thanks, just that your mentioning of 'x' confused me. I am using that elsewhere in the program (int x = str.length();)

Comment: Why can't I upvote an answer to my own question? You should be allowed to, even if you don't have 15 rep. Agreed, Stack Overflow?

Comment: I was referring to `x` because you have the condition `z<x`, meaning the for loop should only progress if that condition is true.  If `z >= 0` and `x <= 0`, then there would be zero iterations.  (and yes, you should be able to upvote and accept answers to your own questions)

Comment: @KirkWoll He has less than 15 reputation and can't upvote answers. He can accept though.

Answer (score 4):

Java requires that every variable is initialized before its value is used.  In this example, there is a fairly obvious case in which the variable is used *before* it is assigned.  The Java Language Spec (JLS) doesn't allow this.  (If it did, the behaviour of programs would be unpredictable, including ... potentially ... JVM crashes.)

In other cases, the compiler complains when in fact the variable in question is always initialized (or so it seems).  Rather than "understanding" your code, or trying to derive a logical proof of initialization, the compiler follows a specified procedure for deciding if the variable is *definitely assigned*.  This procedure is conservative in nature, and the answer it gives is either "it is initialized" or "it might not be initialized".  Hence the wording of the compilation error message.

Here is an example in which the compiler will complain, even though it is "obvious" that the variable is initialized before use:

```
boolean panic;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
    if (i % 2 == 1 && panic) { // compilation error here
        System.out.println("Panic!!");
    }
}
```

The definite assignment rules (specified in the JLS) say that `panic` is NOT definitely initialized at the point indicated.  It is a simple matter for a person who understands the basics of formal methods to prove that `i % 2 == 1` will always be `false`.  However, the compiler can't.  (And even if it could, the code is still in error given JLS rules.)

Answer (score 2):

You've created a reference, but you've never initialized it. Initialize `code` by changing the first line to

```
String code = ""
```

**Edit:** Zavior pointed out that you can pull an initialized string from the cache rather than allocate space for a new one.

But why are you assigning temp to code and then code to temp plus something else? It can be set to `code = code + ca`.

Comment: because I do things in roundabout ways (Sometimes I just don't want people understanding the whole program)

Comment: rather than using String code = new String(), just do String code = "";